# JFolder::create: Infinite loop detected - Are there newer solutions?

Tags: joomla

The issue of JFolder::create: Infinite loop detected is a rather old problem, from 2008. The most recent solution I found was on an old [Joomla forum thread](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=470&t=282892&sid=e58759e2ed8ad0237ef683f8caf3ef77&start=30). However, wanted to know if anyone has a more recent solution in 2023, given that I've been away from Joomla for quite some time now.

Here is the gist of the old solution:

open_basedir /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs:/tmp

Go to global configuration, click on the server tab and entered the following line:

"/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs:/tmp"

The error continued and i noticed when looking at the path which came from the php info file that it included a ":" right before "/tmp". I confirmed that path does not exist on my server but "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/tmp" does so i removed the ":", saved it, and tried to install a component again and it worked.